# How do you change state based on a click in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, react-state, react-state-management

How do you do a simple useState hook based on a user action such as onClick? In the example snippet below, `setCount` is not allowed to be inside a function, and violates the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html), resulting in:

Error: `Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`

```js
const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

function Btn () {
  const myClickHandler = (c)=>{
      setCount(c+1);// <- WHOOPS!! This violates rules of hooks! Hook can't be in a click handler.
  }; 

  return (
    <button onClick={()=>myClickHandler(count)}>
      You've clicked {count} times.
    </button>
  );
};
```

[Here is a link to a fully working example on JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/pgjuk1oz/1/)

Comment: Is that code *not* inside a function component? `return` isn't valid syntax at the top level.

Comment: it's a snippet. the full context would show a standard react file with a function component wrapping the snippet.

Comment: Please give a [mre]. The ESLint plugin doesn't complain when I put that code in a function.

Comment: ok, added link to jsfiddle example.

Comment: Please note the MRE must be **in the question**, not an off-site link. A JSFiddle isn't much use here because yes, it *is* fully working, that doesn't show any Rules of Hooks errors (again, nor does my local setup, although that ESLint rule is enabled). `setCount` *isn't* a hook, even - `useState` is the hook.

Comment: `useState` is a hook that is called at the top level. `setCount ` is not a hook.

Comment: But doesn't `setCount` call the hook? And you are only allowed to call hooks from the top level of a function component, see https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level

Comment: No, `setCount` is *returned by* the hook. Again the hook is `useState`, which *is* called with the component function body. Have you actually seen an error or warning from tooling on this (e.g. from [`eslint-plugin-react-hooks`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#eslint-plugin)), or is this just your own interpretation?

Comment: [also docs is calling it inside a click handler](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#updating-state)

Comment: Yes, my code actually produces the error message. It goes away if I don't use the hook. My code is not identical to the example though.  I will try to create an example that actually reproduces the error, I guess.

Comment: I figured out how to reproduce it: I had accidentally been writing my variables outside of the function component declaration without realizing it. I am updating this question with the broken code to reflect the actual error I was experiencing that caused the problems. Don't need an answer personally anymore, but I think this may be useful for posterity in case others have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to useState (`setCount(c+1)`) is actually correct.

The hook declaration (`const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0)`) is outside and above the function, which is the wrong place. Move it inside the function and everything will work.

Answer (score -2):

just move useState method into your function

const [count, setCount] = useState();
most be use in functiinal component not in your body if file